# Save checkbox state android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, checkbox, activity-lifecycle

I am new on xamarin and i am trying to save my checkbox state even if the app is closed because when i close it the checkbox reset to uncheck state...

also.. the image that was changed resets.. is there any way to preserve both?

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        var seletor = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        var imagem = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

        seletor.Click += (o, e) => {
            if (seletor.Checked)
                imagem.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.estado1);

            else
                imagem.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.estado2);

        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the Preferences?

Check the following: [How to save user settings](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8199/how-to-save-user-settings)

Store the option selected onclose or suspend.. and retrieve onResume / OnLoad

Something like:

```
 // Function called from OnDestroy
protected void saveset(){

    //store
    var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MyApp", FileCreationMode.Private);
    var prefEditor = prefs.Edit();
    prefEditor.PutString("PrefName", "Some value");
    prefEditor.Commit();

}

// Function called from OnCreate
protected void retrieveset()
{
    //retreive 
    var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MyApp", FileCreationMode.Private);              
    var somePref = prefs.GetString("PrefName", null);

    //Show a toast
    RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this, somePref, ToastLength.Long).Show());

}
```

as in the link provided.

Of course you'll need to adapt to your needs and get / populate the value of the checkbox.

If you want, you can also implement some kind of db and use the same mechanism to persist and retrieve settings.

This is usually what I use to store settings and persist values that I need to "remember"

This is an example of how I'm using the same behavior in one app.. not for a checkbox.. but you can see how it works. I removed some code, but I think should be a good example.

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/ApplicationName",
        Icon = "@drawable/Icon")]
    public class PersonalDetailsActivity : Activity
    {
        ...
        private ISharedPreferencesEditor prefEditor;
        private ISharedPreferences preferences;
        ...

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PersonalDetailView);

            preferences = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("AppName", FileCreationMode.Private);


            PopulatePersistedData();
        }

        private void PopulatePersistedData()
        {
            myId = preferences.GetInt(nameof(myData.Id), 0);

            name.Text = preferences.GetString(nameof(myData.Name), null);
            address.Text = preferences.GetString(nameof(myData.Address), null);
            city.Text = preferences.GetString(nameof(myData.City), null);
            county.Text = preferences.GetString(nameof(myData.County), null);
            emailAddress.Text = preferences.GetString(nameof(myData.Email), null);
            phoneNumber.Text = preferences.GetString(nameof(myData.PhoneNumber), null);
            bio.Text = preferences.GetString(nameof(myData.Bio), null);
            rating.Rating = 5;

        }

        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            prefEditor = preferences.Edit();

            myData = new Citizen();

            myData.Name = name.Text;
            myData.Address = address.Text;
            myData.City = city.Text;
            myData.County = county.Text;
            myData.Email = emailAddress.Text;
            myData.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber.Text;
            myData.Bio = bio.Text;

            prefEditor.PutInt(nameof(myData.Id), myId);
            prefEditor.PutString(nameof(myData.Name), myData.Name);
            prefEditor.PutString(nameof(myData.Address), myData.Address);
            prefEditor.PutString(nameof(myData.City), myData.City);
            prefEditor.PutString(nameof(myData.County), myData.County);
            prefEditor.PutString(nameof(myData.Email), myData.Email);
            prefEditor.PutString(nameof(myData.PhoneNumber), myData.PhoneNumber);
            prefEditor.PutString(nameof(myData.Bio), myData.Bio);

            prefEditor.Apply();
            prefEditor.Commit();

            var intent = new Intent();
            intent.PutExtra("CitizenName", name.Text);

            SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
            this.Finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Basically, create a prefs instance onLoad, when the checkbox changes use the Prefs.Put, onResume, prefs.Get

Comment: I see.. but how I create an "onClose " or suspend?

Comment: The events I'm talking about are overrides of the activity... if you notice.. the code you pasted is the OnCreate... is an override... override suspend and resume would be a good idea to review the activity lifecycle.. but my answer is a possible solution.. blz?

Comment: I understand, but i still dont know how to put the checkbox value, so i can use it againg on "get"..is it a boolean? i am trying to use the sharedpreferrence but i have to put some value, and i dont know what value matches the "checkbox".

Comment: You can even store 1 or 0, true or false, sim or não... then convert it to bool.. c'omon... not that hard right?

Comment: [Android Shared Preference](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4758/android-shared-preference) check out this thread
[Android.Preferences.Preference.SharedPreferences Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Preferences.Preference.SharedPreferences/)

Comment: [SharedPreferences.Editor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)
I would say that if you can PutBoolean, maybe you can GetBoolean but anything will work, then compare the value and set it to the checkbox.Cheked property and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i think the problem is that i am verry new with this..i post a code below to show what i am doing, can you help me againg and show what i am doing wrong?