# Radio button is not working when fragment refresh in android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, radio-group

I have some refresh issue that is when I pop up the fragment and come back to previous fragment my radio buttons events are not working until I create new instance of the fragment.

Please help me if you know the solution

```
_rdGrpNewList = view.FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.RdGrp_Cust_NewList);
 rdBtnNew = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.RdBtn_Cust_New);
_rdBtnList = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.RdBtn_Cust_List);
```

This is the code is not triggering when I refresh.It is working when I create the fragment

```
 _rdGrpNewList.Check(_rdBtnList.Id);
_rdGrpNewList.CheckedChange += delegate
        {
        };
```

Fragment refresh code

```
 public void RefreshFragment(AndroidSupV4.Fragment fragment)
        {
            _fragmentTransaction.Detach(fragment);
            _fragmentTransaction.Attach(fragment);
        }
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am a little confused with your issue. What do you mean by "Fragment Refresh" ? Also, the code that is not triggering, where is it placed in the fragment? Is it on the "OnCreate" method?

Comment: I have added fragment refresh code.Like whenever if I change the language within the app instead of creating new instance of the fragment I just refresh fragment.In that time other controls are working fine but radio buttons are not working if I try to change the check event from  code.But manual interaction is working

Comment: After you refresh code, Do you want `RadioButton` revert to the previously selected state? If so, you could achieve it by GetSharedPreferences like this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483047/save-checkbox-state-android-xamarin

Comment: no..after refresh the fragment.Radio button events are not getting trigger via code..but it triggers via manual interaction